# Android App crashed when I update the version of support-v4 and appcompat-v7 from 24.2.1 to 27.1.0

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin

When I had not add android proguard configuration for the v7 support library, my app crashed with these:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater$Factory2.onCreateView(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet)"
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:4127)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:4203)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:1991)
    at android.support.v7.app.f.v(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:374)
    at android.support.v7.app.f.u(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:323)
    at android.support.v7.app.f.b(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:170)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onPostCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:97)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPostCreate(Instrumentation.java:1187)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2386)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2477)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:160)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1368)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5372)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1117)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:810)
```

I guess that it may be caused by the proguard configuration I haven't added. So, I add the configuration of these:

```
-dontwarn android.support.v7.**
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }
```

But, it also caused building failed. I got these message:

```
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Can't write [/Users/looyoo/Documents/welian-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/proguard/release/0.jar] (Can't read [/Users/looyoo/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.0.aar/decb3e4b44f48252475eee23a4f22565/jars/classes.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [android/support/v7/widget/ListPopupWindow$1.class == classes.jar:android/support/v7/widget/ListPopupWindow$2.class]))
```

I also have checked the libraries' v7 support version and v4 support version, there is no different versions.

These is my dependence tree:

```
+--- com.android.databinding:library:1.3.1
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3 -> 27.1.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0
|    |    |    \--- android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.0
|    |    |         +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.0
|    |    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0 -> 27.1.0
|    |    |         +--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0
|    |    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0 -> 27.1.0
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0 -> 27.1.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.0 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.0
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.0 (*)
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.0 (*)
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.0 (*)
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0
|    |         +--- android.arch.lifecycle:livedata-core:1.1.0
|    |         |    +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.0 (*)
|    |         |    +--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0 (*)
|    |         |    \--- android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.0
|    |         |         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0 -> 27.1.0
|    |         |         \--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0 (*)
|    |         \--- android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.0
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0 -> 27.1.0
|    \--- com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:2.3.0-dev -> 3.0.1
+--- com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:3.0.1
+--- com.android.databinding:adapters:1.3.1
|    +--- com.android.databinding:library:1.3 -> 1.3.1 (*)
|    \--- com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:2.3.0-dev -> 3.0.1
+--- project :IMKit
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0 (*)
|    \--- project :IMLib
+--- project :thirdpart
|    +--- com.aliyun.dpa:oss-android-sdk:2.2.0
|    \--- project :common
|         +--- com.android.support:design:27.1.0
|         |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0 (*)
|         |    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0
|         |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0
|         |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.0 (*)
|         |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.0 (*)
|         |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.0
|         |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0
|         |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.0 (*)
|         |    |    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.0
|         |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.0 (*)
|         |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.0 (*)
|         |    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0
|         |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0
|         |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.0 (*)
|         |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.0 (*)
|         |    \--- com.android.support:transition:27.1.0
|         |         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0
|         |         \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.0 (*)
|         +--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0
|         |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0
|         +--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4 -> 2.7
|         +--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1
|         +--- com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48
|         |    \--- com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.48
|         +--- com.tencent.bugly:crashreport:latest.release -> 2.6.6.1
|         +--- com.qiyukf.unicorn:unicorn:3.10.0
|         +--- com.wanjian:sak:0.0.2
|         +--- project :gridpassword
|         |    \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0 (*)
|         +--- com.taobao.android:alisdk-hotfix:2.0.6
|         |    \--- com.taobao.android:alicloud-report:1.0.1
|         +--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1
|         |    \--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.1 -> 2.1.0
|         |         \--- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.0
|         +--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.0 (*)
|         +--- com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding:2.0.0
|         |    +--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.2 -> 2.1.0 (*)
|         |    +--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.0 -> 2.0.1 (*)
|         |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.1 -> 27.1.0
|         \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.2.21
|              \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.21
|                   \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
+--- project :qrcode
|    \--- project :commonui
|         +--- project :thirdpart (*)
|         +--- project :swipbacklib
|         |    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0 (*)
|         |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0 (*)
|         +--- com.gzsll.jsbridge:library:1.1.0
|         \--- android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.0
|              +--- android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.0 (*)
|              +--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0 (*)
|              +--- android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.0 (*)
|              +--- com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0 -> 27.1.0 (*)
|              +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.0 (*)
|              +--- android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:1.1.0
|              |    +--- android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.0 (*)
|              |    +--- android.arch.lifecycle:livedata-core:1.1.0 (*)
|              |    \--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0 (*)
|              \--- android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.0 (*)
+--- project :bdmap
|    \--- project :commonui (*)
+--- project :MPChartLib
+--- project :magicindicator
|    \--- project :common (*)
+--- com.zhy:percent-support-extends:1.1.1
+--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2
|    \--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.0.2
+--- com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.2.21
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.21 (*)
+--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.0
|         \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.13.0
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.0 (*)
+--- com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0
|    +--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0 -> 2.3.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7
+--- com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0
|    +--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0 (*)
|    \--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.0 -> 2.1.0 (*)
+--- com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0
+--- android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.0 (*)
+--- android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0
|    +--- android.arch.persistence.room:common:1.0.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0 -> 27.1.0
|    +--- android.arch.persistence:db-framework:1.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0 -> 27.1.0
|    |    \--- android.arch.persistence:db:1.0.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0 -> 27.1.0
|    +--- android.arch.persistence:db:1.0.0 (*)
|    +--- android.arch.core:runtime:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0 -> 27.1.0 (*)
+--- android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:1.0.0
|    +--- android.arch.persistence.room:common:1.0.0 (*)
|    +--- android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0 (*)
|    +--- android.arch.core:runtime:1.0.0 -> 1.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0 -> 27.1.0 (*)
|    \--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.6 -> 2.1.0 (*)
\--- com.antfortune.freeline:runtime-no-op:0.8.7
```

Comment: I've a similar problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: I haven't solved this, too.